# How to implement event listeners in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-9

I'm working on a Laravel application and I want to implement event listeners. Specifically, I want to trigger certain actions when specific events occur, such as when a user signs up or when a post is published. I've read the Laravel documentation on events and listeners, but I'm still not quite sure how to implement them in my application.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Created an event class: I've created an event class for the specific event I want to listen for, such as `UserRegistered` or `PostPublished`. This class extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable`.
2. Created a listener class: I've also created a listener class that handles the event, such as `SendWelcomeEmail` or `NotifyAdmins`. This class implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` if I want the listener to be queued.
3. Registered the listener: I've registered the listener in my `EventServiceProvider` by adding it to the `$listen` array.

However, I'm still not sure how to trigger the event and make sure that the listener is executed. Can anyone provide a clear and concise example of how to implement event listeners in Laravel? Thank you in advance!

Comment: show us the code you have that does these things ... how is the event dispatched? did you alias the classes correctly in your `EventServiceProvider`? ... you will need to provide some code

Answer (score 2):

You need to dispatch events when a specific event happens.

e.g. on your register code/controller, you need to dispatch a `UserRegistered`
event.

code

`UserRegistered::dispatch($user);`

On dispatch of the event, its listener will be executed.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events#dispatching-events)